# Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "System.Web.Entity". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk

Tags: asp.net, .net, ubuntu, jenkins

i am trying to build .net 4.5.2 application by Jenkins Job on ubuntu 20.04 using mono.
when i build, i get this error:

```
ResolveAssemblyReferences:
  Primary reference "System.Web.Entity".
/usr/lib/mono/msbuild/Current/bin/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2218,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "System.Web.Entity". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test_final6_job1/aspnet4-sample/aspnet4-sample.csproj]
          For SearchPath "{CandidateAssemblyFiles}".
          Considered "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test_final6_job1/packages/Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.0.0/build/../tools/csc.exe",
            but its name "csc"
            didn't match the expected name "System.Web.Entity".
```

this is my csproj file:
https://github.com/mekhamata/aspnet4-sample/blob/dev/aspnet4-sample/aspnet4-sample.csproj
any help how to solve this?